# MySQL - Average number of particular product sold on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write SQL query for "average number of particular product sold by date. On each day is sold min one product".

```
SELECT AVG (COUNT (PID))
FROM SOLD
GROUP BY DATE, PID;
```

P.S. PID means Product ID.

Is this query okay?
Should this give right answer?

Comment: *"Is this query okay? Should this give right answer?"* Try it?

Comment: Since DATE is a function name in MySQL, I think you'll have an issue if that is also the name of one of your columns. Might need to escape the column name.

Comment: Well, don´t have a database. This is question from my lecture. :/

Comment: Post sample input and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read the guied which will help you how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TonyStark [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) helps a lot to test SQL queries when you don't have a DB available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Using `distinct` count of `date` columns

```
SELECT PID, 
       COUNT(PID)/COUNT(distinct date_) as "Avg.Product Sold By Days"
  FROM SOLD
 GROUP BY PID;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think thats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql query below. Basically, it will return the average number of 'SALES' for each product you have. It will group by each distinct product ID. Please provide us the data structure your of table and etc.

```
  SELECT product_ID, trans_date
           Sum(sales_of_product) / COUNT(DISTINCT sold_transaction) AS 'avg'
    FROM SOLD
    GROUP BY product_ID
```

Comment: Ware ( WID, Price, NumberOfWareInShop, NumberOfWareInWarehouse ) 

SOLD( PID, WID[Ware], Date)

and i need to know how much of particular products is sold per date on average